# Indexing array of big documents for lookup of first item in Mongo

Tags: mongodb

I have a `post` document that looks like this:

```
{
  recipients: [{...}, {...}]
}
```

I'm running a query that (periodically) checks for `{recipients.0: {$exists: true}}` to see if there are any recipients (if there are, I send the post to them and remove them from the array).

Each `recipient` is a relatively big document so when I try to put in an index on `recipients.0` I get an `index key entry too large` error.

What's the best way to index the array then? Should I perhaps change the query to look for sth like `{recipients.0._id: {$exists: true}}` and index the `_id` field? Also, would it be beneficial to use a sparse index?

Update: Thinking about it some more, is it possible to create an index that would not really take into account what's *in* the array, just whether the array is empty or not?

Comment: How large is this collection? And how many arrays are empty? Also the size the the subdocument where that exists and the MongoDB version. I'm trying to blow this up by creating large colllections and indexing on the `0` property of the array, but it is not failing for me yet.

Comment: Well, I believe it depends on the size of the entry under the indexed key. When I index the 0th field, it blows up with `index key entry too large` error because the object I'm indexing is too large.

Comment: Well that is what I am asking you. What is the size?

Comment: More than 1024 bytes. But to reiterate, it's not about the size of the collection. It's about the size of the subdocument at index 0 of the array, i.e., the size of the first recipient object. Which in my case in cca 5000 bytes.

Comment: There 5000 bytes. Was not too hard was it. How many fields? Should their always be a consistent field structure? Such as `_id` within each sub-document?

Comment: What do you use to tell the documents one from the other? I imagine an `_id` field is not very descriptive, but a `document.title` would be. If you have such field and you use that to search-by in your other queries then index by that one. I say "other queries" because in this question it seems like you're just querying the first document only, for which I don't imagine you need an index.

Comment: Hmhm, well, the way the app is architected is that it would be more convenient if I didn't have to rely on a certain field to be there. There can be multiple types of documents as recipients and at least one of them does not have an `_id` field.

Comment: Anyway, I understand I could index a field for the documents in the subarray and query for that. But what I'm wondering is whether or not it is possible to have an index without actually having to _know_ what object is inside the array. I'm only interested in whether the array is empty or not.